# JwtAuthProvider issue bearToken in response header that is not httpOnly - ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I have set ServiceStack AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies to true:

```
Config.AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies = true;
```

This did remove httponly from some Set-Cookie in the response header:

[image]

I would like to remove httponly for the Set-Cookie response header for "ss-tok".

I have looked at the options for `JwtAuthProvider` and have not found anything.

Here is my AuthFeature configuration:

```
        Config.AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies = true;

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new JwtAuthProvider
                {
                    HashAlgorithm = AuthSettings.HashAlgorithm,
                    RequireSecureConnection = requireSecureConnection,
                    AuthKeyBase64 = AuthSettings.JwtAuthKeyBase64,
                    ExpireTokensIn        = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireTokensIn"].ToDouble()),
                    ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireRefreshTokensIn"].ToDouble()),
                    CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => {
                            payload["zipCode"] = ((CustomUserSession)session).ZipCode;
                    },
                    PopulateSessionFilter = AuthSettings.PopulateSessionFilterImplementation
                },
                new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(HostContext.Resolve<ITsoContext>()) //HTML Form post of User/Pass
            }));
```

P.S.: I do not have high security concerns for this application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT Token Cookies use the [recommended httpOnly for JWT Cookies by design](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#ajax-clients) to prevent XSS attacks, it’s not overridable.